# VSCode IntelliSence doesn't know `exports` in package.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vite, type-hinting

I am using a library called sinuous, and it has a submodule "sinuous/map".

VSCode doesn't know `map`'s type in `import { map } from "sinuous/map"`, but it does in `import { map } from "sinuous/src/map"`.

I am using vite to write frontend vanilla JS with ESM support. When I write `import { map } from "sinuous/src/map"`, vite is not happy:

```
20:49:07 [vite] page reload user-list.js
20:49:07 [vite] Internal server error: Missing "./map.js" specifier in "sinuous" package
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: D:/dev/web/neohcpp-z/user-list.js
```

This is sinuous's file tree:

```
sinuous
│  package.json
│  README.md
│
├─dist
│      babel-plugin-htm.cjs
│
└─src
        .eslintrc.yml
        babel-plugin-htm.js
        babel-plugin-htm.md
        h.d.ts
        h.js
        htm.js
        hydrate.d.ts
        hydrate.js
        hydrate.md
        index.d.ts
        index.js
        jsx.d.ts
        map.d.ts
        map.js
        observable.d.ts
        observable.js
        observable.md
        shared.d.ts
        template.d.ts
        template.js
        template.md
```

This is part of the `package.json` of sinuous (in my `node_modules`):

```json
{
  "name": "sinuous",
  "version": "0.32.1",
  "description": " Small, fast, reactive render engine",
  "module": "src/index.js",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "types": "src/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./src/index.js"
    },
    "./h": {
      "import": "./src/h.js"
    },
    "./babel-plugin-htm": {
      "import": "./src/babel-plugin-htm.js",
      "require": "./dist/babel-plugin-htm.cjs"
    },
    "./htm": {
      "import": "./src/htm.js"
    },
    "./hydrate": {
      "import": "./src/hydrate.js"
    },
    "./map": {
      "import": "./src/map.js"
    },
    "./observable": {
      "import": "./src/observable.js"
    },
    "./template": {
      "import": "./src/template.js"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src",
    "dist",
    "!**/test/**"
  ],
  //...
}
```

So when I import with path, VSCode sees the `map.d.ts`, but it doesn't when I import with `sinuous/map`.

To make vite happy, I must `import { map } from "sinuous/map"` (which is also apparently more graceful), but then VSCode doesn't know the types.

I have used `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
  }
}
```

This does make TSC happy, and TSC can see the `map.d.ts`, and when I import `map` in `.ts` files VSCode knows the type of `map`. But in `.js` files, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is solved.

`jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "nodenext"
  }
}
```

references:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56412